# Cannot run a script after reboot using Cron

Tags: pi-2, linux, cron

I'm trying to start a script containing cgminer for mining when the raspberry pi reboots however it doesn't.

My crontab contains the following.

```
@reboot sleep 120 && sudo /home/pi/StartVPN.sh
@reboot sleep 120 && /home/pi/Run_Miner_SHA256.sh
0 6 * * * sudo shutdown -r
```

`@reboot sleep 120 && sudo /home/pi/StartVPN.sh` => Runs perfectly after 2 minutes my VPN is connected with the server.

`@reboot sleep 120 && /home/pi/Run_Miner_SHA256.sh` => Never runs and I must run it manually.

`0 6 * * * sudo shutdown -r` => Works fine and the raspberry pi reboots at 6 AM.

My "Run_Miner_SHA256.sh" file contains the following:

```
cd /home/pi/mining/newpac/cgminer && sudo nohup ./cgminer -o stratum+tcp://192.168.100.100:3256 -u 75ZNRZpEqYBM72GwGi6LCjaKM5Ao715ijD -p anything --gekko-newpac-freq 40  >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following line above your line

```
TERM=xterm
```

Comment: thank you very much, this did the job. Excellent

Answer (score 1):

for debugging purposes remove the  >/dev/null 2>&1 & and redirect it to a log file

BTW why do you need the nohup and the & at the end ?

Comment: I'm using the nohup to create a process in the background

Comment: I did what you suggested and the log has this line: Error opening terminal: unknown.

Comment: `nohup` doesn't create a process in the background; `&` at the end does.  `nohup` redirects the standard IO streams (in, out, error) to make the process less prone to fatal "hang-up"s -- eg., while it is running in the background (see `man nohup`).

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

##### First Thing:

WRT your error: You need to remember that `cron` jobs do not run under the same environment as your interactive shell. You can see this by running `printenv` in a `cron` job, and then comparing the output to same command executed from your command line (interactive shell); i.e.

```
@reboot printenv > /home/pi/mycronlog.txt 2>&1
```

and then from the command line:

```
$ printenv
```

As you'll see, there are *substantial* differences! Also note that `cron` defaults to `sh` (not `bash`), and that may not work for all the commands in your script.

I won't try to debug your code, but I will make some observations based on a quick look:

- it's certain that if you either change your `cron` environment, or respect the current environment (e.g. by using full path statements instead of `./`), it will run.
- there is no point using `nohup` in a `cron` job ([REF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585706/286615)). Read `man nohup`
- `./` should be a ***specific path***; e.g. `/home/pi`
- Have you tried something perhaps *less convoluted*?; e.g. instead of:

  ```
  @reboot sleep 120 && /home/pi/Run_Miner_SHA256.sh
  ```

  perhaps try something like this:

  ```
  @reboot sleep 120; /home/pi/mining/newpac/cgminer  -o stratum+tcp://192.168.100.100:3256 -u 75ZNRZpEqYBM72GwGi6LCjaKM5Ao715ijD -p anything --gekko-newpac-freq 40 >/dev/null 2>&1
  ```

  **NOTE:** There are several things left unclear from your question; for example, why send all output to `/dev/null`?, is `cgiminer` a folder name **and** the name of an executable file? (`cgiminer/cgiminer` - or `cgiminer`?)

##### Second Thing:

Using `sudo` in your `cron` jobs works in RPi OS, but it will fail in most distros, and is not "best practice". If you need elevated privileges in a `cron` job, you should run under the `root crontab`:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

When running in the `root crontab`, you don't need `sudo` at all.

Comment: I actually tried with sudo and non sudo, it doesn't run the script. Here is the mycronlog output :
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/pi

Comment: $printenv => https://pastebin.pl/view/7d1a5ce4

Comment: `1st coment:` Sorry - I do not understand... you `tried`... what did you try? Your `mycronlog` output looks correct.   `2nd comment:`  The output at pastebin also looks correct. Note in particular the `PATH` environment variable.  This was only to show how different your `cron` environment is from your interactive shell (the command line). Please see the revised answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more specific, I meant that I used : #sudo crontab -e and #crontab -e . I tried @Oren solution by adding TERM=xterm and it worked now.